# Travis CI build fails for RcppArmadillo-based package

Tags: r, travis-ci, rcpp

I have a bizarre patchwork of Travis CI build fails for a package that runs with no errors on my macOS High Sierra with XCode 9.3 and the current R release. The problems seem to come from an inability to handle the RcppArmadillo-based functions in my package.

The failing build is [here](https://travis-ci.org/japilo/colorednoise/builds/350490355), but to summarize, the package passes on OS X and R 3.3, fails on Ubuntu and R 3.3, passes on OS X and R 3.4, fails on Ubuntu and R 3.4, errors on OS X and R 3.5, and passes on Ubuntu and R 3.5.

The two build fails on Ubuntu occur because the code examples for the RcppArmadillo-based functions in my package fail with an `Aborted (core dumped)` error, which I find singularly uninformative, especially since the package appears to load without any issues according to the package installation logs. Nor do I understand why it works fine on Ubuntu with the development version of R.

The error on OS X and R 3.5 occurs because it can't build RcppArmadillo (even though it could do so on the old and current releases of R.) What I can't figure out is why the package works on both operating systems, but for different releases of R. Is this a problem with my code or a problem with Travis?

My [Travis yml file](https://github.com/japilo/colorednoise/blob/master/.travis.yml) is as follows:

```
language: r
r:
  - oldrel
  - release
  - devel
cache: packages
sudo: false
os:
- osx
- linux
osx_image: xcode9
dist: trusty
install:
  - R -e 'install.packages(c("dplyr", "purrr", "purrrlyr", "Rcpp", "RcppArmadillo", "knitr", "ggplot2", "rmarkdown", "testthat", "covr"))'
compiler: gcc
r_packages:
  - covr
after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'library(covr);codecov()'
```

The install.packages() command is in there because devtools is known to behave unpredictably in the development version of R.

**Update for people Googling this problem in the future:**

Through careful experimentation, I figured out exactly what broke the build on R 3.3 and 3.4 on Linux. It was a simple index out of bounds error in a for loop. Why the function was still able to work completely as expected on Mac and Linux + R-devel despite this error is still an open mystery.

Comment: macOS and RcppArmadillo do not play nicely since parallelization was added. Do you use parallelization in any of your code? FYI: The toolchain in R 3.5.* is likely changing again compared to the clang4 binary + xcode cli system headers used to compile.

Comment: Can you make it smaller/simpler to hone in on where it may fail?  Also, you have a [pretty clean sheet at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_colorednoise.html) so all that is a little puzzling.

Comment: @coatless I don't actually use parallelization in any of my code at the moment (though I'm hoping to in future versions) but I had hoped that wouldn't be a problem because I added a configure file that turns off the -openmp flag if parallelization is not available on the system.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm afraid I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean I should make a new repository with a much simpler version of my package (say, with just one RcppArmadillo function) and see whether that fails?

Comment: That is one possibility. You can also skip the travis instances where it works -- no need fot the full matrices.  Then when you have _a_ failure, dig in and analyse it.

Comment: Update: I have figured out exactly what's breaking it. One of my Rcpp functions calls on RcppArmadillo functions in the same .cpp file and wraps the output to NumericMatrix format. When I comment out the lines calling the RcppArmadillo functions and wrapping them, the package works on all three releases on Linux. I have no idea why or how to fix it, however.